# Scalatest MustBe throwing error despite having same content

Tags: scala, scalatest

I´m running some unit tests in Scala and I aḿ facing a weird behavior,
I have one class defined as the following:

```
final class ComputationResult(Team: team, scoreResults: ScoreResults, idToLabel: IdToLabel)
```

and the definition of IdToLabel is the following:

```
final case class IdToLabel(totalLabel: Option[String],
                           buyLabels: Option[Map[String, UUID]],
                           customLabels: Option[Array[String]])
```

I´m running some unit tests to compare two objects of the ComputationResult class.
But despite being the same, I´m receiving failure message:
After doing some debug, I found out that it´s indicating that the IdToLabel field is not the same for the two objecst, and it outputs the following error message:

```
Expected :IdToLabel(Some("Total"), Some(Map("020e748f-988c-4851-93fa-73ed84a3f6f7" -> 020e748f-988c-4851-93fa-73ed84a3f6f7)), Some(Array("grVdW7KlYIw6")))
Actual   :IdToLabel(Some("Total"), Some(Map("020e748f-988c-4851-93fa-73ed84a3f6f7" -> 020e748f-988c-4851-93fa-73ed84a3f6f7)), Some(Array("grVdW7KlYIw6")))
```

AS you can see both objects are the same, So I..m not sure what´s really happening.

did anyone faced something like this before ?

Comment: I would bet the problem is due to `Array`, `Arrays` are not equal by value but by reference, so unless you used the same memory address for both they are effectively different values. - My advice, use `List` or any other real collection.

Answer (score 0):

The output can be misleading as it's a string output.

*For instance the string `"0"` and the numeric value `0` would appear in the same way in the diff output (assuming it's actually possible to have both of these values in a single type, likely `Any`..).*

You can put a breakpoint and check equality of each value composing your case class in your IDE to troubleshoot this easily.

In your case, I'd suspect `UUID` or `Array` (thanks Luis!) to not be compared the way you expect it to but that's only a guess.